# Using Contracts in Laravel Lucid context

Tags: php, laravel

Using the [great Lucid structure thing](https://github.com/lucid-architecture/laravel) have a question:
what about the storage abstraction and using something like contract with several implementations?

For example, `Shopping Cart` functionality.
When user logged in, shopping cart data should be stored in a database.
When user logged out, the data storing in the session.

So, there is an option:

- create set of jobs named, for example, `Eloquent`:

  `App\Domains\Cart\Jobs\Eloquent\AddToCartJob`,

  `App\Domains\Cart\Jobs\Eloquent\FlushCartJob`

  `...`
- similarly create other set of jobs, `Session`:

  `App\Domains\Cart\Jobs\Session\AddToCartJob`,

  `App\Domains\Cart\Jobs\Session\FlushCartJob`

  `...`

But how to switch between each of jobs set depends of the condition: user logged in or no?
It looks like should be some kind of the repository, inside each of methods should be used some job(s) from first or second set.

Some kind of:

```
//...
use App\Domains\Cart\Jobs\Eloquent\AddToCartJob;

class EloquentCart implements CartContract
{
    //...

    public function addToCart(array $data)
    {
        //...

        return $this->run(new AddToCartJob($data));
    }
}
```

and:

```
//...
use App\Domains\Cart\Jobs\Session\AddToCartJob;

class SessionCart implements CartContract
{
    //...

    public function addToCart(array $data)
    {
        //...

        return $this->run(new AddToCartJob($data));
    }
}
```

in the `AddToCartFeature`:

```
//...

class AddToCartFeature extends Feature
{
    //...

    public function handle(Request $request, CartContract $service)
    {
        //...

        return $service->addToCart($request->all());
    }
}
```

and, finally, using of contextual binding with condition `is user logged in?`.

Is it normal solution or contract-implementation should be developed by another way in Lucid context? Is it normal practice to create one more layer between Feature and Job, or exists another way to switch between implementations?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to abstraction and design patterns it is recommended that they exist within the code rather than in Lucid's components (Feature, Operation, Job); keeping the architecture in the periphery rather than the foreground of your code.

Your multi-repository approach is a great starting point. Assuming you have:

- `App\Data\Repositories\CookieRepository`
- `App\Data\Repositories\DatabaseRepository`
  Now we can have two separate jobs, each accessing the corresponding repository:

**Cookie**

- `App\Domains\Cart\Jobs\AddToCookieCartJob`
- `App\Domains\Cart\Jobs\FlushCookieCartJob`

**Eloquent**

- `App\Domains\Cart\Jobs\AddToDatabaseCartJob`
- `App\Domains\Cart\Jobs\FlushDatabaseCatJob`

This ensures that jobs remain atomic and are named explicitly for what they do. This helps when skimming through a Feature or an Operation to know what we're doing without having to check namespaces and get confused with similar job names, or having to deal with namespace aliases (see more on Jobs in [the docs](https://lucid-architecture.gitbook.io/docs/components#096c6dc4-d4cc-4cb1-836e-c06412c4d97c)).

Now that we've established the groundwork, we'll need to call these jobs depending on the `logged in?` condition. Given that features shouldn't deal with the intricacies of the units of work, this would be a greate place for an Operation.

- `App\Operations\AddToCartOperation`

  - `if logged in` → `AddToDatabaseCartJob`
  - `else` →  `AddToCookieCartJob`
- Same goes for `App\Operations\FlushCartOperation`

Now our Feature won't have to know these details, just run the operation:

```php
class AddToCartFeature extends Feature
{
    //...

    public function handle(Request $request, CartContract $service)
    {
        //...

        $status = $this->run(AddToCartOperation::class, [...]);

        //...
       return $this->run(SomeOtherJob::class, compact('status'));
    }
}
```

As for the rest of the code, you may use any design patterns that fit your case.

> The names above are only for the example, please rename according to your conventions.

I hope that I've understood your question correctly and that this answer helps!

Comment: but if the features list is enough long?
Should I check `is user logged` in every operation?

What if in future will appear more sub conditions for storing the data to database (for example, only advanced plan users can store cart and continue to shopping from another machine, base plan users store data only in session). It will be not conveniently to handle all conditions in every operation.
Wouldn't it be better to keep conditions in one place, like contextual binding with condition?

Comment: I don't see a problem in checking whether a user is logged in several times during the execution within each operation. Because each operation has its own logic, and if its logic depends on that condition then there's no harm in having it. In fact it is needed.

As for the cases with several conditions, I suggest you take a look at Strategy Design Pattern, which might be helpful in your case? https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy/php

If the operations you are talking about are similar then maybe they should be jobs in an operation that has the common condition?

Comment: What about using such operations not in the features? If I have `GetCartDataOperation`, is it a good practice to use this operation, for example, inside a view composer or middleware?

Comment: Ideally operations should be run in features or Artisan commands when needed. In the case of rendering it is best to prepare all the data needed for your view/composer and pass it on to a job that does the rendering.

Nevertheless, Lucid is flexible and allows for running operations in almost any context. If you see that it works best for you to run it from views or view composers then go for it, but make sure you make it a pattern (guideline) to follow everywhere in your code and achieve consistency.

Between operations in views and view composers, i'd go for composers only (personally).